# Cannot switch keyboard layouts

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

My default keyboard layout is Norwegian (from the 12.04 installation procedure). But I also want to  use Icelandic.

Two layouts in the "system settings" → "keyboard layouts" is one too many. I cannot switch either using a shortcut or in the Panel.

The Panel tells me I have switched, but the letters I type are Norwegian, even when the Panel seems to have switched to Icelandic.

My  language for menus and windows ("system settings" → "language support") is English. "Regional formats" → "Display numbers, dates ….": English Denmark,

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "one to many". Please clarify, what have you changed in Keyboard layouts? Do you see a keyboard icon in the upper right?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this:

```
sudo setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle no,ru
```

This maybe can help you but you have to do it everytime you log in to your system. You can add this command to execute

Comment: Yes, Ashutosh! It worked. But is there no file I can open to edit in the line?

Comment: If it worked for you, then please make it the answer, file would have been different, so i think there is another file to have that line. PLease make it the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

OP-provided answer, probably inspired by @ashutosh

---

To enable toggling between two keyboards for current session:

```
  sudo setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle no,is
```

To permanently set several keyboards (Norwegian, Icelandic, Spanish)

```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard
```

Edit line 2 thus:

```
  XKBMODEL="pc105"
  XKBLAYOUT="no, is, es"
  XKBVARIANT=""
  XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Answer (score 0):

go keyboard settings -> options 
and from the popup click the arrow at Key(s) to change layout and select the shortcut you need

Answer (score 0):

Add (and install) the layout it is using but move the wanted layout to top on the keyboard layouts list (System settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Layouts). Reboot. Logout. Login checking that the wanted layout is selected in the login screen. Reboot and test if working.