# Russian phonetic keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard

The keyboard layout GUI in 12.04 system settings is not responding on my laptop. In a different post a workaround was found (see: [Cannot switch keyboard layouts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129700/cannot-switch-keyboard-layouts)).

Problem now: Having manually altered the file /etc/default/keyboard I can now access all the keyboard layouts I want except for one: Russian phonetic. (i.e. the letters are placed where the equivalent Latin letters are - qwerty) This keyboard was in the old Gnome and it is still listed in the "system settings" keyboard GUI. But the GUI is not responding.

I can toggle between the official Russian keyboard and Norwegian with the command:

```
sudo setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle no,ru
```

But `ru phonetic` is not understood. What is the code for the phonetic Russian keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

I use it like that:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,compose:menu -layout 'us,lt,ru' -variant ',,phonetic_winkeys'
```

The main thing is `'us,lt,ru'` and `',,phonetic_winkeys'`. In your case it will be `-variant ',phonetic_winkeys'`

Comment: Useful answer, but I haven't found a `phonetic_winkeys` option. I get an error. I've referred to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305373/164309) to find out that I needed `phonetic`.

Comment: To add up to previous comment, based on the output of `grep phon.*ru: /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`, I believe `phonetic_winkeys` applies to Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what nationality you are. Norwegian?  I am Czech, so I use the standard Czech QWERTZ keyboard. So I prefer Czech Russian phonetic keyboard:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:win_space_toggle -layout 'cz,cz' -variant ',rus'
```

The problem is that this layout has switched YZ keys to the standard Czech keyboard. So I had to modify the file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/cz
```

First I found the section:

```
// phonetic layout for Russian letters on an CZ (QWERTY) keyboard
xkb_symbols "rus" {
```

There I changed these lines:

```
//    key <AB01> { [       Cyrillic_ze,       Cyrillic_ZE,            z,        Z ] };
key <AD06> { [       Cyrillic_ze,       Cyrillic_ZE,            z,        Z ] };
//    key <AD06> { [     Cyrillic_yeru,     Cyrillic_YERU,            y,        Y ] };
key <AB01> { [     Cyrillic_yeru,     Cyrillic_YERU,            y,        Y ] };
```

This way I got Russian phonetic keyboard with Czech QWERTZ layout. So I hope it can help you when you need more detailed setting of Russian phonetic keyboard even in Norway. :-)

Most settings and options can be found here:

```
less /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```