# How to install Russian phonetic keyboard on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, keyboard, russian

I need to install a Russian phonetic keyboard. From keyboard settings, I only get the "йцукен" keyboard, but I need the "яшерты" one. Does anyone know how I can do this directly, or how can I make my own keyboard from the Terminal?

Comment: Consider to ask or search on https://forum.ubuntu.ru . Here the similar question was [closed 2 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/q/828763/66509). Also it would be great if you add keyboard layout image to the question.

Comment: At the very least, I see in system-settings of KDE, keyboard configuration tab, when you set "ru" layout, you can choose a "phonetic variant". Not sure about Unity settings. Anyway, you tagged the question as "command-line", in which case it's likely [a duplicate of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130413/russian-phonetic-keyboard-layout?rq=1).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "install ... keyboard". Is there a plastic keyboard, or do you mean a keyboard layout?