# Change of Keyboard Layout won't apply

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have selected the german layout but the keyboard is still set to (I guess) english layout (no ä, ö, etc and @ on shift + 2). But if I change the layout to english and then back to german the change applies until I restart my pc. During the installation I selected german layout and there it worked  properly during the installation but after the installation finished it changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (and install) the layout it is using but move the wanted layout to top on the keyboard layouts list (System settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Layouts). Reboot. Logout. Login checking that the wanted layout is selected in the login screen. Reboot and test if working.

https://askubuntu.com/a/329625/182024

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue having 2 keyboards English and Arabic on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I switched from LightDM to GDM3 on Ubuntu 18.04 which helped. Now I can switch language from the login screen.

if you don't have GDM3 you can install with

sudo apt-get install gdm3
to switch from LightDM to GDM3 run:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Enter the password if asked then in the dialog click ok and then select GDM3 and press ok again.

Restart the system.

Hope that helps!