# 14.04.1 unable to switch layout

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, I've added russian layout in System settings > Region & Language > Input Sources. Also, I've installed gnome-tweak-tool, and set input source toggle hotkey to Ctrl+Shift. But still, the only way to change layout is by clicking keyboard layout indicator.

I have tried several fixes for 13.10 found on AskUbuntu, but no luck:

- [Cannot switch keyboard layouts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129700/cannot-switch-keyboard-layouts)
- [How to use Alt+Shift to switch keyboard layouts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-to-switch-keyboard-layouts)

My settings:

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
```

- http://i59.tinypic.com/ezn53q.png
- http://i59.tinypic.com/4l0mbs.jpg